# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'vectorize'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**I have such Python code:**

```
import Regression as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
NN = t.Neural_Network()
yHat = NN.forward(t.X)
y2 = np.vectorize(t.y)
y3 = np.vectorize(yHat)
plt.bar([0,1,2],y2, width = 0.35, alpha=0.8)
plt.bar([0.35,1.35,2.35],y3, width = 0.35, color='r', alpha=0.8)
plt.grid(1)
plt.legend(['y', 'yHat'])
```

i would print bar charts for two numpy arrays values but the error shows like that

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: `y2` and `y3` are functions, not arrays.  It doesn't make sense to pass either to a plot function.  Read the documentation for `np.vectorize` before you try to use it any more.  It's often misused and mis understood.